# Diplays an error message when data already exists

Tags: vba, excel

I know it's a simple problem but I am having a hard time with this, I have 2 textboxes (txtUs,txtPass), and a command/log-out button which validates data and let them enter their username and password.now if they inputted wrong password or username,
error message will appear. but if they got the two correct it will then display a message "You have successfully log-out". The problem is that, the program cannot find data if there is a blank rows before it. it only recognizes data if datas' doesnt have a blank column before them that starts from column A2..Any help/corrections will be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim user_name As String
Dim user_pass As String

If Not IsNull(UserForm4.txtUs) Then
    user_name = UserForm4.txtUs

Else
    MsgBox "Username or password is Incorrect"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNull(UserForm4.txtPuss) Then
    user_pass = UserForm4.txtPuss
Else
    MsgBox "Username or password is Incorrect"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 2
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 1).Value = ""
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 1).Value = user_name And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 2).Value = user_pass Then
        MsgBox ("You have been logged-out")
        UserForm5.txt_Mon_in.Text = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 4).Value, "hh:mm AMPM")
        UserForm5.txt_Mon_out.Text = Format(Time, "hh:mm AMPM")
        UserForm5.Label1 = Sheets("employees").Cells(counter, 2).Value & Sheets("employees").Cells(counter, 3).Value & Sheets("employees").Cells(counter, 4).Value
        UserForm5.Label2 = Date + 14
        UserForm5.txt_Mon_Rate.Text = Sheets("employees").Cells(counter, 6).Value
        UserForm5.Show
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 5).Value = Time
        UserForm4.Hide
        Set UserForm4 = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Loop
MsgBox ("Username or password is incorrect")
```

Comment: Add a variable to count the number of consecutive blanks (reset to 0 when you hit a non-blank cell) and exit the loop when the count is greater than some threshold - eg. exit after 10 consecutive blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to a for loop through the usedrange

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
        counter = c.Row
    Next
End Sub
```

added check to skip empty cells:

```
Dim user_name As String
Dim user_pass As String

If Not IsNull(UserForm4.txtUs) Then
user_name = UserForm4.txtUs

Else
MsgBox "Username or password is Incorrect"
Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNull(UserForm4.txtPuss) Then
user_pass = UserForm4.txtPuss
Else
MsgBox "Username or password is Incorrect"
Exit Sub
End If

Dim counter As Integer

Dim c As Range
For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
counter = c.Row

If c.Value <> "" then
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 1).Value = user_name And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 2).Value = user_pass Then
MsgBox ("You have been logged-out")
UserForm5.txt_Mon_in.Text = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 4).Value, "hh:mm AMPM")
UserForm5.txt_Mon_out.Text = Format(Time, "hh:mm AMPM")
UserForm5.Label1 = Sheets("employees").Cells(counter, 2).Value & Sheets("employees").Cells(counter, 3).Value & Sheets("employees").Cells(counter, 4).Value
UserForm5.Label2 = Date + 14
UserForm5.txt_Mon_Rate.Text = Sheets("employees").Cells(counter, 6).Value
UserForm5.Show
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 5).Value = Time
UserForm4.Hide
Set UserForm4 = Nothing
Exit Sub
End If
counter = counter + 1
Next
MsgBox ("Username or password is incorrect")
```

Comment: @wittrup..I may not fully understand some of these but as a begginer I'm pretty sure i could learn from this. Thanks!